# CompletableFuture, thenCompose method

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, threadpool, completable-future

I have some misunderstanding about [***the contract***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-) of `thenCompose(Function<? super T,? extends CompletionStage<U>> fn)`. Here is what's said there:

> Returns a new `CompletionStage` that, when this stage completes
>   normally, is executed with this stage as the argument to the supplied
>   function.

It seems the function accepts the result of this `CompletionStage`, not the `CompletionStage` itself. So what do they mean  by that?

And what about the task represented by the returned `CompletableFuture`?

```
Runnable r;
ExecutorService es;
Function<Void, CompletableFuture<Void>>f;
//...
CompletableFuture.runAsync(r, es)
.thenCompose(f);
```

Does it mean, a task, represent by `CompletableFuture` returned by `thenCompose` will be executed in the same `ThreadPool` as the `Runnable r`?

Comment: The doc is badly worded - it should read "*with this stage's result as the argument to the supplied function*". `f` will be executed using `es`.

Comment: The way, the `CompletableFuture` will be completed, has already been defined by the function `f` *before* it returns it.

Comment: @Holger What do you mean? First we call `runAsync` which submits the `Runnable` to the `ThreadPool`. It might happen that the completable future is completed **before** `thenCompose` is called on it (evaluation of the arguments to `thenCompose` might take some time).

Comment: The code of your `Function<Void, CompletableFuture<Void>>` must contain a creation of a `CompletableFuture` instance that the function will eventually return. The way, this `CompletableFuture` is created, e.g. via `runAsync`, determines, how it will get completed. The fact, that the function has been invoked via `thenCompose`, has no influence on that.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a mistake in the JavaDoc. Other methods such as [`thenApply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-) use the following formulation:

> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes
>   normally, is executed **with this stage's result as the argument to the
>   supplied function**. […]

(emphasis is my own)

Also, in Java 9, the [formulation is now](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/jigsaw/spec/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-):

> Returns a new CompletionStage that is completed with the same value as
>   the CompletionStage returned by the given function.
>
> When this stage completes normally, **the given function is invoked with
>   this stage's result as the argument**, returning another
>   CompletionStage. When that stage completes normally, the
>   CompletionStage returned by this method is completed with the same
>   value. […]

As to which thread/thread pool will execute the function, this will actually depend on the implementation.

For [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), this is indicated at the top of the documentation:

> Actions supplied for dependent completions of *non-async* methods may be performed by the thread that completes the current CompletableFuture, or by any other caller of a completion method.

In practice, there seem to be 2 possible cases:

1. If this stage is already completed, then the function is applied immediately on the thread calling `thenCompose()`;
2. If this stage is not completed yet, the function will be applied on the thread that completes this stage (correct me if wrong).

Note that there is no "task" inside a `CompletableFuture`. The only "task" that the returned `CompletableFuture` does is binding the result of the one returned by the passed function with itself. You are in charge of executing the task that will complete the `CompletableFuture` your function returns.

Comment: Actually, not even the “binding” is a task of the returned future; it’s a task bound to the future returned by the function. Or, in other words, `CompletableFuture`s are *never* associated with the tasks that will eventually complete them, they don’t even know them. They only now the dependent stages they have to notify.